# JSON.stringify not display properly, while use multiple javascript object

Tags: jquery, json, stringify

I have use generate the javascript multiple object based my page result, then convert to JSON string. but `JSON.stringify` not display properly. I don't know why display like this. I have added example of my coding

```
var sample_object = [];
var sub_array = [];
sub_array["type"] = 'I';
sample_object.push(sub_array);

console.log(sample_object);
console.log(JSON.stringify(sample_object));
```

Result :-

```
[Array[0]]
    0: Array[0]
        length: 0
        type: "I"_
        _proto__: Array[0]
        length: 1__proto__:
        Array[0]
```

JSON.stringify Output

```
 [[]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sub_array["type"] = 'I';` This statement will have no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you can't have named arguments in an array. You need to change `sub_array` to an object. Also note that the variable you have named `sample_object` is actually an array. Here's a working version with appropriately named variables:

```
var sample_array = [];
var sub_object = {};
sub_object["type"] = 'I';
sample_array.push(sub_object);

console.log(sample_array);
console.log(JSON.stringify(sample_array)); // = '[{"type":"I"}]'
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7ga138fb/)

You can even shorten the first four lines to just this:

```
var sample_array = [{ type: 'I' }];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Worked

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: You can have custom properties in Array! Array instance is Object instance too...

Answer (score 0):

Only Array indexes from 0 to a.length-1 are used by JSON.stringify, it is ok. If you want to create another properties, use object...

e.g.

```
var x={type:"i",data:[]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help